# Sata HDD spins for half a second and stops

Tags: hard-drive, bios, sata

I'm trying to plug a 1TB Sata HDD. I already have a 500GB one. However, the SO (Win7) doesn't detect it, neither does the bios.

I tried switching SATA ports with the older HDD and with a DVD Drive, it doesn't work. I tried switching power cables, not detected. I even tried connecting it alone (e.g. not connecting the other HDD and DVD Drive).

The bios configuration is in "native (enhanced)"; so I don't think it is a problem there.

I noticed that the new drive spins for about half a second and stops when I push the power button. It also takes significantly longer to boot with the new HD plugged.

Faulty hard drive?

Comment: Do you hear any clicking noises when it spins up? Those are the most usual sign of hard-drive failure and generally the clearest indicator. In fact, they are something to listen out for even with an otherwise working hard-drive as they can give warning of an impending failure.

Comment: Nope. I can't hear any clicking sounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, faulty hard drive. More specifically: electronic failure. A recovery company will be able to save your data and it would be pretty cheap too if it's actually the electronics. Last time I paid $70 for one 1 TB + cost of a new HDD at the same size. All they did was to exchange the controller card and copy the data to the new HDD.

Comment: Even if it is brand new? Seems a bit of bad luck.

Comment: According to Google lab the three first months is the most critical in a HDD life. Any electronic attachment such as active backplane between HDD and motherboard also reduce life span.

Comment: I see... Well, it's still in warranty; so I'll be able to save some money.

Comment: Sure you do, if you bought it in a civilized country.